# Find the maximum of the lengths of all filenames in a directory

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have to write a script  that takes a directory name as an argument and writes to standard output the maximum of the lengths of all filenames in that directory. If the function’s argument is not a directory name, write an error message.

How can I do that

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You seem to be asking a "[Give me a fish question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2686/how-should-you-respond-to-give-me-a-fish-rtfm-questions)". Both you and those who find your question later would be best served by a "How to Fish answer". You will likely get more focused answers if you [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are having trouble.

Comment: I am not seeing how this question is too broad... printing an error message if a condition is not met seems pretty reasonable to me! How would this benefit from being narrowed down?

Comment: What have you done already? Do you have an approach that you've already tried? Can you ask about a specific problem that you've had while trying this for yourself?

If you haven't tried anything yet, then you're just asking someone on Ask Ubuntu to do work for you; that's not what the site is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A script rather than a function. This prints the number of characters in the longest filename, which is what I understood you wanted:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# include hidden files
shopt -s dotglob
# if the first argument is a directory
if [ -d "$1" ]; then
    # move to that directory
    cd "$1"
    # set a variable to 0
    long=0
    # loop over all the files
    for i in *; do
        # print the filename - remove this line after testing
        echo "$i"   
            # if the length of the current filename is longer 
            # than the value of the variable long, assign the
            # length of the current filename to long 
            (( (${#i} > $long) )) && long=${#i}
    done
        # print the value of long
        echo $long
    # if the first argument wasn't a directory, print an error
    else
        printf "%s\n" "Not a directory"
fi
```

This makes use of the `dotglob` setting, which causes globbing with `*` to include hidden files. To see the effect of it, run these commands in your home directory:

```
ls -d *
shopt -s dotglob
ls -d *
```

To turn off `shopt` settings, use `-u` for example `shopt -u dotglob`.

We need to check the argument is a directory, so we use `if` and the `test` command (in its `[` form) which has a test for directories, `-d`:

```
if [ -d "$1" ]; then
```

this means, if the first argument passed to the script is the name of a directory that exists, then do the following. `$1` is the first argument, and we enclose it in double quotes to stop the shell from performing further expansions on the value of the variable.

We need to go into the directory, because we need to get the length of the filename, not the whole path (absolute or relative). We don't want this:

```
$ for i in ~/*; do [ -d "$i" ] && echo "$i"; done
/home/zanna/custom
/home/zanna/Desktop
/home/zanna/Documents
/home/zanna/Downloads
...
```

because if we count the length of `$i` we will get the length of the full path. We could do some text processing antics (and maybe some cleverer tricks I don't know) to get rid of the path, but parsing filenames is generally unreliable and if we change directory we can easily get the shell to count characters for us using `${#var}` to give the length of `var` (I believe that this counts *characters* and not bytes). Note that scripts run in a child shell, not in the current shell, so if a script changes directory, the working directory of the shell that calls the script isn't affected.

My script uses `for` to loop over the files in the directory. The line that does the work is

```
(( (${#i} > $long) )) && long=${#i}
```

This means, if the length of the current value of `i` is greater than the current value of `long`, then assign the length of `i` to `long`. Since we first set `long` to 0, the first filename will always be longer than `long` (because it's as short as possible). Thereafter, only the length of longer filenames will be able to replace the value of `long`. Since we know `${#i}` and `long` will only contain integers, we don't need to protect them with double quotes. `((` creates an arithmetic context in Bash so we can use `>` with its mathematical meaning (thanks to [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) for pointing that out to me elsewhere).